# TextInputLayout and EditText hint visible

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-textinputlayout, hints

I am facing a very weird issue after updating my Android Support Libraries, particularly `'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'`. Take a look at the following screenshots:

[image] ______ [image]

Note that the same code is working fine for email, country and phone fields but for Name field, the hint "Name" is also visible behind the user's name.

Following is the code:

**Email code:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.touchd.app.ui.views.FontEditText
        android:id="@+id/textEmail"
        style="@style/loginEditTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/email_text_view"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Programmatically:

```
mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textEmail);
mEmail.setText(userProfile.email);
```

**Name code:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.touchd.app.ui.views.FontEditText
        android:id="@+id/textName"
        style="@style/loginEditTextView"
        android:hint="@string/name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
        android:text="@string/no_name_specified" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Programmatically:

```
mName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textName);
if (userProfile.name != null && userProfile.name.length > 0) {
    mName.setText(userProfile.name);
}
```

**Style**

```
<style name="loginEditTextView" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">19sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
</style>
```

You can see the code is similar. Can anyone help me out here? Is it a bug in Android Design library or am I doing something stupid?

Comment: could you post styles and FontEditText implementation?

Comment: `FontEditText` is only setting typeface, nothing else.

Comment: I've added the style

Comment: for `FontEditText` the question is what it extends

Comment: maybe I got it. It seams to me that the problem is on the gravity property: in email field you override the style with "top|center_horizontal" but in name field you don't so it remains "center".

Comment: @Christian it is extending `EditText`.

Comment: @carlol let me check that

Comment: @carlol No, it's the same

Comment: You should use or extend `android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText` inside the `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` - maybe this helps.

Comment: It's a bug in 25.1.0, as mentioned in my answer. Roll back to 25.0.1 for now until this issue is fixed by Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a regression in v25.1.0 of the Support Design library as mentioned [in a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41496301/469080). It'll likely be fixed in a future release. Roll back to v25.0.1 for now.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230171

**EDIT** Fixed as of 25.2.0 apparently. Will confirm when I get chance to check.

Comment: Okay, but then why is it working for email, country and phone?

Comment: Yes it has resolved the issue. Stupid Android

Comment: @BugsHappen It works fine when text is added by the user. This bug only happens for pre-populated EditText fields.

Comment: Please don't post the same answer to multiple questions. Flag questions as duplicates if they've already been answered here.

Comment: This issue is fixed in Support Library Version 25.2.0.